# Dialog Alert in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I need to click to button 'b_avanca_c' if the user don't fill the field 'editTextNomeVelhinho' present the dialog alert and after the user fill the 'editText' must forward for layout 'C_aviso', as well as if 'editText' is filled from the beginning. In this case the aplications always goes to 'if' and even after it is filled in the dialog box always appears.

```
   fun b_avancar_c(view: View) {
    val nomeIdoso :String
    nomeIdoso=editTextNomeVelhinho.text.toString()

    if(editTextNomeVelhinho.text.isEmpty()) {
        buttonComecar.setOnClickListener {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@B_menu)
            builder.setTitle("Atenção")
            builder.setMessage("Deve colocar o seu nome para continuar")
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar") { dialog, which ->
                //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "continuar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()


        }
    }
    else {
        val it = Intent(this, C_aviso::class.java)
        startActivity(it)
    }
}
```

Code layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.asus.aprendecomigovelhinho.B_menu">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonComecar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:text="Começar"
            android:onClick="b_avancar_c"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.983"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.349" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNomeVelhinho"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.921"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.026" />



            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In your current code, when the function b_avancar_c is called, it will check if your editTextNomeVelhinho is empty. If it is empty, it will simply set a click listener on buttonComecar. Then any time buttonComecar is pressed, even if the EditText is empty, it will call that Alert dialog. If you just want to show the dialog when the b_avancar_c function is called and the EditText is empty, you should remove the click listener and move the dialog builder stuff out of that block.

Comment: Can you share your layout file

Comment: thx @VishnuM. that way it already gives

Answer (score 1):

Text from edittext is got when clicking on button so it will not be empty everytime.

```
fun b_avancar_c(view: View) {
    val nomeIdoso :String
    nomeIdoso=editTextNomeVelhinho.text.toString()

    if(editTextNomeVelhinho.text.isEmpty()) {
        buttonComecar.setOnClickListener {
             val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@B_menu)
             builder.setTitle("Atenção")
             builder.setMessage("Deve colocar o seu nome para continuar")
             builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar") { dialog, which -> 
           //Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"continuar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }
             val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
             dialog.show()
           }
     }
     else {
           val it = Intent(this, C_aviso::class.java)
           startActivity(it)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to use an Alert Dialog using Kotlin found in the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder? = activity?.let {
        AlertDialog.Builder(it)
    }

    builder!!.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
        .setTitle("Log Out")

    builder.apply {
        setPositiveButton(R.string.user_log_out_dialog_no) { dialog, id ->
            val selectedId = id
        }
        setNegativeButton(R.string.user_log_out_dialog_yes) { dialog, id ->
            val selectedId = id
        }
    }
    val dialog: AlertDialog? = builder.create()

    dialog!!.show()
```

Keep in mind that some strings are hardcoded.